# Waiting for Sub Tasks to Finish in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to create a simple game using JavaFX. The game consists in a main game and sub-games, which the player may have to play, depending on the result of the main game. In the end, the main game has to update it's state (p.e.: score) depending on the sub-games result.

I made a simplified and generalized version of how I have implemented the game logic:

```
Result play(Player p) {
    Result r = p.play(this);
    for(SubGame game : r.getSubGames())
    {
        p.play(game);
    }
    update(r);
    return r;
}
```

This game works perfectly in the terminal, since it has a linear execution.
But using JavaFX (implemented in the Player), I cannot control the flow of the program properly, because of the game loop.

I have followed [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1) tutorial to handle multiple screens for the main game and sub-games. The Player class can successfully change the screen to a sub-game, using the handler. But the update no longer waits for the sub-games to be played, and this function returns while the player is mid-game.

I am trying to keep the game logic separate from UI, so changes to the code showed above shouldn't be dependent on the interface framework.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an event-driven approach, setting the values of observable properties, and responding when they change.

For example, you might encapsulate the state of the game with

```
public class GameState {

    private ObservableList<SubGame> currentGames = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<SubGame> getCurrentGames() {
        return currentGames();
    }

    private ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<SubGame> currentGame = new ReadOnlyObjectProperty<>();

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<SubGame> currentGameProperty() {
        return currentGame.getReadOnlyProperty() ;
    }

    public final SubGame getCurrentGame() {
        return currentGameProperty().get();
    }

    public GameState() {
        // initialize sub game list...
    }

    public void nextGame() {
        int index = currentGames.indexOf(currentGame.get());
        if (index < currentGames.size() - 1) {
            currentGame.set(currentGames.get(index + 1));
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        currentGame.set(currentGames().get(0));
    }

    public boolean hasMoreGames() {
        return currentGames.indexOf(currentGame.get()) < currentGames.size() - 1 ;
    }
}
```

And similarly you might have some observable state in your `SubGame` class:

```
public class SubGame {

    private final BooleanProperty finished = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public BooleanProperty finishedProperty() {
        return finished ;
    }

    public final boolean isFinished() {
        return finishedProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setFinished(boolean finished) {
        finishedProperty().set(finished) ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now your game logic is just implemented with listeners:

```
void play(Player p) {
    Result r = p.play(this);
    GameState gameState = new GameState();
    gameState.currentGameProperty().addListener((obs, oldGame, newGame) -> {
        newGame.finishedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFinished, isNowFinished) -> {
            if (isNowFinished) {
                // maybe update score etc based on state of newGame...
                if (gameState.hasMoreGames()) {
                    gameState.nextGame();
                } else {
                    // logic here for "all games are finished...
                }
            }
        });
    });
    gameState.start();
}
```

Obviously the details of how you implement this depend on your requirements etc, but this general approach should work for anything you need.

Comment: If you need a concrete example, I have a human vs computer Tic-tac-toe (noughts and crosses) [here](https://github.com/james-d/TicTacToe) which follows similar principles.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. I think I got the idea, but there is still the problem of mixing UI related stuff with the game logic, which I want to avoid.
Beside that, this method will return immediately even thought the bonus are being played, right?

Comment: The method will return immediately, yes. Where is the UI mixed with the logic though? The `SubGame` and `GameState` class I showed only contain logic, no UI components.

Comment: The point is that there's no problem with the method returning immediately. Updated code example to show how you might process logic that needs to happen only when everything is complete.

Comment: There are no UI components used directly, but you use a GameState which depends on JavaFX components, like FXCollections.
These dependencies don't make much sense if I want to use the same game with different type of UI.

Comment: Maybe, though really there's nothing to stop you using those in any model (they don't depend on starting the FX toolkit, etc, and are really just plain java objects designed for lazy notification). But if you prefer, just use bound JavaBeans in the model and JavaBeanPropertyAdapter classes in your JavaFX UI code. The principal is still the same: you *cannot* block the UI thread to wait for something: the UI won't get rendered, so you must use some kind of event-driven notification-subscriber approach.

Comment: I got it, thank you for all the feedback. To conclude, would it be bad practice to call the play method inside a Task thread and use Platform.runLater() on UI modifications?

Comment: In theory, I think that would work, but it gets tricky because the user input necessarily comes from the FX Application Thread (where user events are processed). So you would have to take care to manage state properly when it is being accessed from two threads. Additionally, `Platform.runLater(...)` requires the FX toolkit to be running, so (at least in a naive implementation of this approach), you end up with the model being more tightly coupled to JavaFX than using FX properties.